# How to add an expiration time to a reset password link?

Tags: php, mysql

I am tring to add an expiration time of 30 minutes to my reset password link but I'm stucked for loooong time.
I'm usding PHPMailer for sending email. In my DB I have added a token and expire_token_time for the link but I don't know how to set a limit time of 30 minutes to this link?
here is my code:

```
   $reset_token = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
   // created and expiration token date
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
   $token_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $date = new DateTime($token_date);
   $date->add(new DateInterval('PT30M')); // add 30 minutes to token
   $expire_token = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   //Content
   $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
   $mail->Subject = 'Reset Password ';
           // here is my link to users mail box
           // how i keep this link active for 30 minutes ?
   $mail->Body    = "To reset your password click the link bellow <br />
                     <a href='http://localhost/varprospects/changePassword.php?token=" .
                     $reset_token . "' > Change Your Password </a> <br /> The link will be expired 
                     in 30 minuntes!
                    ";

   // find the requested user's password
   $selectStmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email,password from var WHERE email=:email");
   $selectStmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
   $selectStmt->execute();

   if ($selectStmt->rowCount() == 1) {
      $row = $selectStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if ($row) {
        // if the user exist i add the random token and it's epiration date to the DB
         $updateStmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE var SET token = :token, token_expire = :tokenExpire WHERE email = :email;");
         $updateStmt->bindParam(':token', $reset_token);
         $updateStmt->bindParam(':tokenExpire', $expire_token);
         $updateStmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
         $updateStmt->execute();

         $mail->send();
         echo "<p class='text-center font-weight-bold mt-5'> Please check your email </p>
               <p class='text-center'> An email has been set to the following adresse: <br />" . $row['email'] . "</p> ";
      } else {
         echo "Email doesn't exist !";
      }
```

I am not sure should i insert the token expiration datetime to DB or no the creation datetime.
because the time token generate and expire, there is 30 minutes difference.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html). It will disable expired tokens automatically.

```sql
CREATE EVENT disable_old_pw_reset_token
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
UPDATE var SET token = NULL WHERE token_expire < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I assume that `token_expire` stores expiration datetime value.

The presence of the index by `token_expire` (by single column or as a prefix) is reasonable.

Do not forget to enable Event Scheduler.

Comment: thanks for answering. yes token_expire store expiration time. Now i'm working as local if need to export my DB to other system do i need to enable again event_scheduler or not. if yes doesn't take much time ?

Comment: @WahidAMINI Event scheduler must be enabled on this "other system" (another MySQL server) if you want the event procedures to be executed. To enable event scheduler you have to set according global variable - this needs in a second. To make this permanent, you have to edit the settings file and ES will start during server startup (in most cases you must uncomment according row in settings file and save).

Comment: I come back to another question regarding event_scheduler. I have written another Event Scheduler I don't why it's not working. I would like to set the reserve = 0. the event should run everyday at midnight 00:01:00. when the expiration date (exp_date) is less then current date time ``` CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS disable_reserved_value_of_prospect
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
   STARTS '2022-03-30 00:01:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
UPDATE prospect SET reserved = 0 WHERE exp_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;```. But my script doesn't work I don't know why ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @WahidAMINI If you have another question then you must create another topic with this question. You may refer to previous topic if you think that this is useful (but in this case I think this won't help and hence not needed).

Comment: @WahidAMINI *I would like to set the reserve = 0.* - compare with *UPDATE prospect SET reserve**d** = 0 WHERE ..*

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure should i insert the token expiration datetime to DB or no the creation datetime

...it doesn't really matter. The point is that when you receive the token, you should compare that stored time to the current time, and act accordingly.

However I'd say it might be a little bit better to set the expiration time in the database. That way you're not relying on a second piece of data (the timeout period) in order to check whether the token has expired, so it's simpler. But that's really the only difference.

If you need to know how to compare two datetimes in PHP and see which is greater, there are [lots of existing resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+compare+two+datetimes) which cover that process in detail.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering. is it possible to give an example. I did research on comparing dateTime.

Comment: And what did your research reveal? What did you try? What went wrong? There are endless examples available, but I don't know what you did or where you got stuck, so I can't give you a targeted, useful one which isn't just a repeat of something you can already read